# NodeJs Multer s3 Sequelize

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sequelize.js, multer-s3

Hi i am currently trying to implement a sign up process. the user has already been registered into my database and is now required to upload their id and profile picture. My fronted is currently working and connected to the backend. but the images are not getting stored in my database.

here is my post request:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
  region:process.env.AWS_REGION
})

function getFilename() {
  return new Date().toISOString() + '-' + uuidv4();
}

function getTransforms() {
  const fileName = getFilename();
  return {
    transforms:[
      {
          id: 'full',
          key: (req, file, cb) => {
            let fname = file.originalname.split(".");
            cb(null, fname[0] + '-' + fileName + "_full.jpg")},
          transform: (req, file, cb) => cb(null,
              sharp().resize(2000).jpeg({
                  quality: 50
              }))
      },
      {
          id: 'thumb',
          key: (req, file, cb) => {
            let fname = file.originalname.split(".");
            cb(null, fname[0] + '-' + fileName + "_thumb.jpg")},
          transform: (req, file, cb) => cb(null,
              sharp().resize(100).jpeg({
                  quality: 30
              }))
      }
  ],
  metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
    let fname = file.originalname.split(".");
    cb(null, { 
        fieldName: file.fieldname, 
        key: fname[0] + '-' + fileName
    });
}
}
}

router.post(
  "/",
  async (req, res) => {

    const multerS3Config = multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
      shouldTransform: true,
      acl: 'public-read',
      contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
      ...getTransforms()
  });

  const upload = multer({
      storage: multerS3Config,
      limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 }
  });


    upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount"))(req,res,async(error)=>{
        console.log('req',req.body)
            const paths = await req.body.images.map((file) => ({url:file.imageUrl,type:file.type }));

    console.log(paths)

      User.findAll().then(async(user)=>{

        const user_mobilenumber= user.map(x=>x.mobilenumber);
        const new_user = req.body.mobilenumber;


        const aes256gcm = (key) => {
            const decrypt = (enc) => {
              enc = Buffer.from(enc, "base64");
              const iv = enc.slice(enc.length - 28, enc.length - 16);
              const tag = enc.slice(enc.length - 16);
              enc = enc.slice(0, enc.length - 28);
              const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
              decipher.setAuthTag(tag);
              let str = decipher.update(enc, null, 'utf8');
              str += decipher.final('utf8');
              return str;
            };
          
            return {
              decrypt,
            };
          };
          
          const aesCipher = aes256gcm(key);


          for (const x of user_mobilenumber) {
            const y = aesCipher.decrypt(x);
    
            if (new_user === y) {
    
             User.findOne({
                where: {
                  mobilenumber: x,
                },
              })
                .then(async(user) => {
                  console.log(user)

                  if (!user) {
                    return res.status(404).send({error:"User Not Found."});
                  }

        await Document.create({
            userId:user.id,
            images:paths.map((x)=>({images:JSON.stringify(x.url)})),
            type:paths.map((x)=>x.type)
        },
        {include:[User]}
        ).then(
            res.status(201).send({
                userId:user.id,
                images:paths,
                msg: "upload successful",
            }),
        )

                })
            }}
      }) 
    })
  }
);
```

here is my log from my req.body

```
req {
  mobilenumber: '+207777777777',
  images: [
    {
      imageUrl: 'url',
      type: 'idfront'
    },
    {
      imageUrl: 'url',
      type: 'idback'
    },
    {
      imageUrl: 'url',
      type: 'profilepicture'
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the error i am currently getting :

```
  ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: string violation: images cannot be an array or an object,string violation: type cannot be an array or an object
```

in my pgadmin i have a table called Documents with the columns id, userId, images and type. where for each image uploaded should be stored with its type and user id.

Each user can have many documents but each document belongs to 1 user.

also here is my relationship:

```
User.hasMany(Document, { foreignKey: "userId" });

Document.belongsTo(User, 
  { foreignKey: "userId" }
  );
```

Here are my models:

Users.js

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../config/database");
const Document = require("./Documents");

const User = db.define(
  "User",
  {
    firstname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    passcode: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    dob: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      mobilenumber: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    tableName: "Users",
);

module.exports = User;

User.hasMany(Document, { foreignKey: "userId" });

Document.belongsTo(User, 
  { foreignKey: "userId" }
  );
```

Documents.js

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../config/database");
const User = require("./Users");

const Document = db.define(
  "Document",
  {
    images: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    type: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: "Documents",
  }
);

module.exports = Document;
```

Comment: Show modle defintions

Comment: @Anatoly hi, i have updated my question with the model definitions

Answer (score 0):

It seems, in your **Document** model you've defined the field `images` to be `String` but you're passing an `Array` instead.

So try changing following line:

```
images:paths.map((x)=>({images:JSON.stringify(x.url)}))
```

to:

```
images:paths.map((x)=>({images:JSON.stringify(x.url)})).join()
```

then when you read from DB just apply `images.split(',')` to get an `Array` of image-urls.

**OR**

update **Document** model for `images` field to accept `Array` instead of `String` type.